Is it feasible to take blueberry cuttings in October?
We're making another run to my late grandparents' property in Tennessee to take care of some things. Earlier this year I got some cuttings in late spring; I had gotten them to root but a freak heatwave dried them out and killed them.
If it were possible to get (maybe hardwood?) cuttings next month, I wouldn't have to potentially miss being able to come for the spring again. I've always heard late spring/early summer is ideal, but would it be possible to get cuttings outside that range? Would I have to wait until winter for completely dormant hardwood cuttings?

If you get some hard freeze you may get some troubles, OTOH blueberries should be enough hard for freeze.
Also ideally few weeks after leaves fall, so that root have time to store starch and other nutrients from leaves and trunk.
Maybe try to so some cuttings now, and try to do next spring.
It is a trade-off: time availability and ideal cutting and period. I would tend in less cutting in such cases.

It's not ideal, but it is possible to take blueberry cuttings in October. Hardwood cuttings should be taken in the winter for optimal results. These are normally collected in late autumn or early spring, when the plant is completely dormant. The incomplete hardening off of October cuts could lower success rates. If you must take cuttings in October, use rooting hormone and select wood that is starting to fall dormant for better odds. Alternatively, for best rooted success, think about taking softwood cuttings in late spring or early summer of the following year.
